# Python action to find out if selection made in one layer is inside polygon in another layer

Tags: pyqgis, select

Here is my beginning of code but it is not working.

```
layer1 = iface.activeLayer()
for feature in layer.getFeatures(): 
    if feature.geometry().within(layer2.geometry):
    print ('yes')
```

My goal will be to display the result in an information window.

Comment: what seems not to be working? It looks like you haven't set layer2.geometry to anything?

Comment: You need to indent the if line. Add a reproducable code snippet

Comment: What is `layer2.geometry` supposed to be?

Comment: @MrXsquared: this is the second layer (it is composed of a multipolygon). the one that contains or does not contain the polygon selected in the first layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this with [QgsVectorLayer.aggregate()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.aggregate)

```py
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer1')[0] # I just prefer this style for testing...
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer2')[0]

for feature in layer1.getFeatures(): 
    if feature.geometry().within(layer2.aggregate(aggregate=19,fieldOrExpression='$geometry')[0]):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

Indeed it is a little fiddle to understand the documentation of [QgsVectorLayer.aggregate()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.aggregate) but basically it works similar to the expression. `aggregate=19` means `GeometryCollect` as [stated in the docs](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsAggregateCalculator.html#qgis.core.QgsAggregateCalculator.GeometryCollect). As expression just use `$geometry` as you would in field calculator. As `aggregate()` returns a tuple, you need to get the first value by `[0]`. `[1]` would return a bool and `[0]` the result from aggregate, in this example a geometry, but it could also be an array, integer, string or whatever.

---

To go only for selected features just use `layer1.getSelectedFeatures()`:

```py
layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer1')[0] # I just prefer this style for testing...
layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer2')[0]

layer2_agg_geom = layer2.aggregate(aggregate=19,fieldOrExpression='$geometry')[0]

for feature in layer1.getSelectedFeatures(): 
    if feature.geometry().within(layer2_agg_geom):
        print('Selected Feature ' + str(feature.id()) + ' is within ' + str(layer2.name()))
    else:
        print('Selected Feature ' + str(feature.id()) + ' is not within ' + str(layer2.name()))
```

Comment: it's complicated but interesting.
I will use it if needed. The script makes it possible to calculate the number of plots of layer 1 and the number of plots of layer 1 inscribed in layer 2.
For my part, I want to test if a parcel selected in layer 1 is registered in one of the perimeters of layer 2.[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/we0DU.jpg

Comment: @ MrXsquared : thank you it works perfectly!